# What is the meaning of "rage," in this exchange

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, middle-english

Merriam-Webster (on line) offers no help with the meaning of "rage" (verb) in this context; 
"swage" is presumably 'assuage' (fade).

> *Youthe speke to his selfe & sayd:*
>    With women me lyst both play & **rage.**
>   *Angel:* To þi saule it is gret damage.
>   *þe fende:* Jf þou be holy in þi yong age,
>   Þi sorose sal incres & þi myght **swage.**

The conversation is between  a Youth, the Guardian Angel, and the Devil (the Fiend).Br Lib Additional 37049 with added emphasis and modernised punctuation] Carthusian miscellany in Northern English 1460 -1500. ff.28v {Copyright remains with the British Library, who allow study.
[image: Verse and picture from the original page]

'Violence' and 'madness' don't seem to fit in the phrase 'both play & rage.'

**Update:** "play and rage" occur together twice in Canterbury Tales "A"
**Update .2.** Fixed links to the BL pages time out and freeze to protect the site. But it should still be possible to find the Digitised page as " Additional_MS_37049 " If not, find it in  Elizabeth Sears: The Ages of Man *plate 21.*

Comment: @Jim this is just a 'typical' youth (third of seven ages)who says he enjoys (lysts (sic)) to play and rage. Someone who sets out to go mad or get in a rage with the women he goes out with is unusual, yes?

Comment: *Do not go gentle into that good night.
Rage, rage against the dying of the light.* - Dylan Thomas

Comment: @HotLicks: while Dylan Thomas came to my mind and, I gather, did not want the meaning of that poem too literally analysed, I think it has very little bearing on this text.

Comment: Could you give us more details about the text, including a date (range)? A link for ”Br Lib Additional” would also clarify things.

Comment: The link is broken, is it listed here: http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/BriefDisplay.aspx  What year was this written? What title is the piece? Title of book?

Comment: @Mari-LouA it says 1460 - 1500

Comment: The link in your question is definitely not working. Can ELUers still be searching through its archives? Don't think so :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry about the link. BL seem to have set a time limit on all fixed links. I think the Oxford Dictionary does the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think the relevant sense is probably this noun sense (from the *Middle English Dictionary*):

> 6. Amorous longing or desire, lovesickness; also, a fit of carnal lust or sexual desire; a feeling of passion or love; **~ of love**, an ardent passion; **loves ~**, the fervor of love.

[[link](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED35765)]

So I think the verse means something like, "I like both sex and desire" (*[plei](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED33653)* meaning, among other things, "sex").

Comment: This sounds close, but I am a little surprised at the order of _plei and rage_, as it seems anticlimactic — perhaps just for the rhyme, but that seems weak.

Comment: Do you think "lyst" is a late or Northern spelling; or is it a pun on 'lyst'  / 'list' ? Does the construction "lyst_play" tell us which?

Comment: @Hugh: Although the MED doesn't include *lysten* in the headword for the *list* entry, quite a few of its citations spell it that way. (See http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED25754&egs=all&egdisplay=open.) So I don't think we need to invoke any pun explanation. As for the construction "[IO] lyst [S]" . . . that's not the most common construction I see in the quotations for *list*, but I don't think it's so exceptional as to warrant special explanation. Dunno. (Disclaimer: I'm *really* not knowledgeable about ME; I'm just going based on what I see in MED.)

Answer (score 12):

Online Etymology has some interesting background for [rage](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=rage); until the mid-13c., it meant

> "to play, romp," from rage (n.) [After that a new meaning was acquired:] Meanings "be furious; speak passionately; go mad" first recorded c. 1300.

So, it may be a repetition of play (as in "romp and play"), or it may be fight/go mad/whatever. I'm not sure the Angel's advice is helpful in deciphering its meaning (*To þi saule it is gret damage.*)

Interestingly (again) is [*swage*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=swage):

> "to shape or bend by use of a tool"

but that was later than your poem.

By the time of Milton's writing, *swage* did mean assuage.

Answer (score 3):

[Google's definition](https://www.google.fr/search?q=define:rage) includes:

> - continue with great force or intensity.
>     "the argument raged for days"
>     synonyms:   be violent, be at its height, be turbulent, be tempestuous, be uncontrollable, thunder, rampage 
>     "a tropical storm was raging"
> - (of an illness or fire) spread very rapidly or uncontrollably.
>     "the great cholera epidemic which raged across Europe in 1831"
> - (of an emotion) have or reach a high degree of intensity.
>     "she couldn't hide the fear that raged within her"

I think it means, like, "be intense" or "burn intensely like a fire".

It may also implies some uncontrollable insanity (from the Latin word for "rabies").

Comment: Those are all modern meanings, which do not help much with what is evidently a much older text; if before 1300, medica’s answer pretty much rules them out.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the words *play* and *rage* were often paired in Middle English, the one word complementing the other.

*[Middle English Dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cBX9pQlHZoIC&pg=PA1029&lpg=PA1029&dq=sche%20began%20plei%20%20rage&source=bl&ots=QU-zcicBRM&sig=H0UismEJYd0wqA6VhkevchdBFOI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7tpLd07fNAhViOpoKHY0XDUAQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=sche%20began%20plei%20%20rage&f=false)* By Hans Kurath
 <sub><sup>CT abbreviation for *Canterbury Tales*</sup></sub>

> **pleien**  *(V)*
>   **2.** (a) to play amorously; make love, engage in sexual intercourse
>
> (al393) Gower CA 1.1764:
>   *Thei were wedded in the nyht.. And sche began **to plei and rage**.*
>
> c1250 Body & S.(4) 29:
>   *Bodi, þu ne mait nout lepen **to plaien*** [vr. leiken] ***ne to rage.***
>
> **5.** (a) to make light or frivolous talk, jest, joke; *~with wordes,* boast; *in pleiinge wise*, jestingly: (b) to make sport, tease: *~of*, make fun of (sth.);  *~upon*, ridicule (sb.).
>
> (c1390) Chaucer CT.Rv.A.3958:
>   *Was noon..That with hire orste  **rage or ones pleye***.

*A New English Dictionary On Historical Principles*, volume VIII, [page 107](https://archive.org/stream/ANewEnglishDictionaryOnHistoricalPrinciples.10VolumesWithSupplement/08.p1.NEDHP.QR.Oxford.Murray.1914.#page/n129/mode/2up)

**rage** NOUN

> **6.** A violent feeling, passion, or appetite. Also, violence, severity, height (*of* a feeling, etc.).
>   […]
>   **b.** Violent desire; sexual passion; heat.
>
> ?*a* **1366** Chaucer *Rom*. *Rose* 1657
>   When I was with this rage hent That caught hath many a man and shent.
>   **1390** Gower *Conf.* 111.271
>   That ilke fyri rage in which that thei the lawe [of marriage] excede.
>   **1500-20** Dunbar *Poems* 1xxxiv.8
>   Quhone the biche is jolie and on rage.

**rage** VERB (emphasis **mine**)

> **†3**. To behave wantonly or riotously; to take one's pleasure, **to play**. Const *with* (a person).
>
> • a 1300 *Body & Soul in Map's poems* 347
>
> *Body, miht thou nought lepen to **playen ant rage**.*
>
> • 1303 R.Brunne *Handl. Synne* 7896
>
> ***To pley*** wyþ wommen and **to rage**.
>
> • 1390 Gower *Conf*. I. 101
>
> *Sehe began to **plei and to rage.***

Comment: Very nice! +1, and I admire your google-fu!

Answer (score 2):

Is it not me lyste (that is, my lust) that both play and rage. With sense of rage as in a fire burning. An adolescent response to the sight of the attractive woman that the angel is urging to be controlled.

Comment: That is an interesting triple meaning then. 'List' - root which only survives in the antonym 'listless.' Lyst' which survives in lie, lay. And your suggestion, Lyste/ lust. They're all likely to be there as subtexts, I'd think.

Answer (score 1):

I used the above answers some and googled some, but my takeaway is:

Youth speaks to himself and says:
With women I have sex with sometimes lightly and sometimes carnally
Angel: To your soul it is great damage
Devil: If you be holy in your young age
Your offspring will increase an your character will be molded

swage = the [shaping of metal](https://www.google.com/search?q=old%20english%20sorose#safe=active&q=define%20swage) (the gripping tool was called a swage)
sorose = the [bearing of sori](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sorose) which are [spores](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sori)
play = casual sex for the fun of it
rage = serious sex either carnally or with heart and emotions (marriage intent?)

<s>Comment:  I really would have expected the devil's words to be more polar to the angel's.  Perhaps they are in that the angel is concerned with the eternal soul and the devil is concerned with the temporal earthly results.</s>

**Edit:**

---

Thanks @Hugh.  That makes more sense. So the devil's comment becomes:
*If you be holy in your young age, your sorrows will increase and you will be teased* (a piece of metal being swaged would be beaten flat by a hammer).

Comment: See also for rage https://www.jstor.org/stable/43345939

Comment: I think "sorose" is Northern Middle English for 'Sorrows,' from the context. But thank you for your take, and the useful link to Douglas Moffat's paper.